# issues with custom filter for ListView with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

i have a arraylist with custom objects.

```
public class Info implements Serializable {

public String name;
public int Type; 
public long start;
```

}

and i am using it in this way

```
 public class myLogAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Info> implements Filterable {
    ArrayList<Info> items;
    ArrayList<Info> searchitems;
     Context context;
     private Filter filter;
    public myLogAdapter(Context context, int listView,
            ArrayList<Info> List) {
        super(context, listView, List);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.items = new ArrayList<Info>(List);
        this.searchitems = new ArrayList<Info>();
         this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        if (filter == null)
            filter = new NameFilter();

        return filter;
    }

    private class NameFilter extends Filter
    {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                //ArrayList<Info> list = new ArrayList<Info>(searchitems);
                results.values = items;
                results.count = items.size();
            } else {
                ArrayList<Info> newValues = new ArrayList<Info>();
                for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                    Info item = items.get(i);
                    if(item.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        newValues.add(item);
                    }
                }
                results.values = newValues;
                results.count = newValues.size();
            }       
            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            searchitems = (ArrayList<Info>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }
```

}

### calling it like this ->

```
LogAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
```

But this is not filtering the list.On filtering the list showing all the result not the sorted one.Please help me figure out what is the problem.

Thanks

Comment: i have chaged it like this still it is not working

Comment: '@Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                items = (ArrayList<Info>) results.values;
                clear();
                int count = items.size();
                for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
                {
                    Info pkmn = (Info)items.get(i);
                    add(pkmn);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            
          '

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that the problem is in the `publishResults()`-method. It is a bit unclear how you handle your lists, but I think the problem is this;

The list of items which is bound to the adapter is the `items` list. in your `publishResults()`, you put your search result in the `searchitems` list, and tell the adapter that the data is updated by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.
However, your adapter is still bound to the `items` list, which haven't updated. You'll have to either change the data in `items`, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, or recreate the adapter.

My suggestion is this;
In the constructor, set both `searchitems` to the list, and `items` to a copy of this list.
Call the constructor using the `searchitems`.
When filtering, the filter will now look through the original list (saved in `items`), and the adapter-bound `searchitems` will update after each filtering.

Answer (score 0):

here the ans

```
  @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(mAdapterList);
            results.values = list;
            results.count = list.size();
        } else {
            ArrayList<String> newValues = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < mAdapterList.size(); i++) {
                String item = mAdapterList.get(i);
                if (mIsRTO) {
                    if (item.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        newValues.add(item);
                    }
                } else if (item.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    newValues.add(item);
                }
            }
            results.values = newValues;
            results.count = newValues.size();
        }
        return results;
    }
```